# WorkFlow Ensure operations are performed in order

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I was given an assignment for school that says to create a Workflow that looks like:

```
Authentication ->if (Authentication) then { 
    getallcompanies(); 
    selectcompany();
} else {
    error -> terminate;
}
```

It says I need to authenticate the user. If successful, the user can "choose" to listcompanies. After that, they can select a company.

My problem comes in when I try to do getallcompanies followed by selectcompany. My get-all works but my select fails!

My workflow looks like:

[image]

And my Error message:

[image]

I'm using the TestClient by pressing F5 so that I can debug the Workflow before making an actual client. I re-arranged the functions and noticed that the select works but the get won't work. So in other words, the second receive-request never works regardless of the order of the functions. Double clicking the second function will always throw that error for me :S

What am I doing wrong? how can I fix it?

Comment: Pictures of errors are almost always worthless.  *Copy the text from the error details view, then paste it into your question as a quote.*

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the persistence store. Check the executation status, suspension exception, suspension reason. It may give you some hints.